# What is Lysoferrin?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology

I was going though my Guyton and Hall Medical Physiology when I came across the name of an antibacterial lysosomal enzyme - Lysoferrin. It said that Lysoferrin "binds to iron and other metals that are essential for bacterial growth." I looked across the web to find some context about it but found every site quoting the exact same Guyton lines. Some more information about this enzyme would be a real help.

Comment: Have you looked to see if your text provides any primary references to their claim? I'm wondering if this is just an outdated term for something else. From the description, It sounds a bit like [Lipocalin-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipocalin-2). Lactoferrin and Ferritin are also iron-binding proteins that can be unregulated during infections, but they both serve other functions in maintaining iron homeostasis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Japanese patent filed by Raymond Jay Bergeron, Jr [JP2000514089A](https://patents.google.com/patent/JP2000514089A/en) notes lysoferrin as the siderophore
*N<sup>1</sup>*, *N<sup>4</sup>*-*bis* (1-*oxo*-3-hydroxy-3,4-dicarboxybutyl) diaminobutamate. The US counterpart of this patent, jointly filed as US application No. US08/783,306 and later issued as [US 5,739,395](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5739395A/en) covers rhizoferrin in its embodiments. So it seems that the term lysoferrin is just another name for rhizoferrin, perhaps a translation aftefact?

Rhizoferrin [Drechsel, H. *et al.*  (1991) *Biol. Metals* **4**:238–243](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01141187) has the following structure [image: rhizoferrin].

Edit: Just to be clear, lysoferrin is not an enzyme, but the siderophore pictured above.

Here’s from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siderophore):

> Siderophores are small, high-affinity iron-chelating compounds that are secreted by microorganisms such as bacteria and fungi and serve primarily to transport iron across cell membranes, although a widening range of siderophore functions is now being appreciated. Siderophores are among the strongest soluble Fe<sup>3+</sup> binding agents known.